# Adafruit QT Py S3 4/2 and ov2710 camera

Tags: arduino-esp32, adafruit, adafruit-circuitpython, uvcvideo

I have installed CircuitPython 8 on an Adafruit QT Py S3 4/2 mem. I also have a ov2710-based camera. Actually I have two, one with an USB cable, and one wired to a STEMMA connector so it can be attached that way. I find no information about how to use this camera (on google). I find CP drivers/libs for a couple of other ovXXXX cameras. Being a standard UVC camera, is it possible to use this "combo" for a simple DIY webcam and stream video over Wifi? Anyone having experience with this camera model, could it work with some of the other drivers?

The board runs Arduino code as well, so if there are drivers available on that platform it'd be just as interesting.

Edit: Board runs and the attached temp/moisture sensor and motion sensor works just fine.